# Client side encryption for messaging app?

Tags: cryptography

I am trying to develop a web messaging app with end to end encryption so that I can learn more about encryption. My backend is Python running flask.

I want to use a hybrid encryption for the messages, where a message is encrypted with a symmetric algorithm (AES?) and then the key is asymmetrically encrypted (RSA?) and sent to the database.

So a few questions:

- Is this the best and most secure way to do this?
- Would this have to be done in the frontend? Is that secure?
- How exactly would I implement this in JS?

Also, I was planning on generating and storing the private keys in Local Storage, would it be better to instead generate them server side and encrypt them? If so, how would I encrypt it securely?

Comment: If you use HTTP**S**, you don't need all that. If you don't, then you should.

Comment: *"How exactly would I implement this in JS?"* - Find libraries that help you with that or do everything for you. Nobody is going to just give you the code for that. That would be too broad. Anyway, you should just use libnacl / libsodium if they are available in JS.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I want the data to be encrypted in the database, doesn't https just secure the transmission?

Comment: Yes, you would still have to implement hybrid encryption, but you wouldn't need to do it in JS. If you're using asymmetric encryption, you need to make sure that the public key that is delivered to the browser can be trusted. This is not an assumption that can generally be made, because any kind of JavaScript code can be injected into a HTTP connection. You would need HTTPS (with TLS) to protect the public key from being changed, but if you have that, you don't need JavaScript encryption anymore.

Comment: A e2e messagving app is not really a good place to learn about encryption given that it is very hard and there are only a few systems that are deemed truly secure.

Comment: If you want to examine a truly secure e2e messaging system look at [Signal](https://whispersystems.org/docs/). On the extreme end there is Apple that uses HSMs and destroys the smart card admin keys after setting up the HSM cluster, they have no access so can't respond to subpoenas.